# Scroll en chat automatico y colocar un stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día,estoy realizando un chat con (jquery,ajax,mysql) y quiero  que haya un scroll que baje cada mensaje nuevo  pero deje de bajar cuando haga scroll.
revise y funciona el scroll automático con este código

'''

```
function ScrollDown(){
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
    var h = elmnt.scrollHeight;
   $('#content').animate({scrollTop: h}, 1000);

}
sd=setInterval(function(){ 
  var receiver_id = $('#senderC').val();
  if(receiver_id!=''){ScrollDown();}
}, 4500);
```

'''

Intente con esos códigos y no se como parar el scroll automático cuando se hace scroll y luego que sea automático de nuevo intente con esto pero no me resulta se traba.

'''

```
$("#content").on("scroll", function(){
 clearInterval(sd);
 setTimeout(renew,8000);
  });
function Renew(){
sd=setInterval(function(){ 
  var receiver_id = $('#senderC').val();
  if(receiver_id!=''){ScrollDown();}
}, 4500);
}
```

'''

Comment: Podría añadir la estructura HTML y CSS ?, oh incluir un JSFiddle ?

Comment: No veo la necesidad de hacer scroll automático, creo que debería hacerse solo al recibir un nuevo mensaje. Crea una variable global `var goDown = true;`, dentro de ´scrollDown()´ vas abajo solo si la variable es verdadera; Cuando el usuario manipule el scroll, pon la variable a falso y nuevamente a verdadero cuando lleve el scroll hasta abajo.

Comment: Triby gracias por la ayuda.lo que hice fue crear una función con mensajes nuevos y que vea justamente eso, con un count a mi bd. luego cree una variable global y que la compare con este dato si son diferentes hago el scroll y actualizo datos.Por lo del onscroll estuve leyendo que es una función muy pesada para el cliente así que lo deje de lado.